# Entity Framework 6 code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework, I want to add new tables to my database that have already created with code first but they are not reflecting in the database.

Here is my code:

```
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.Admin> Admins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.Exam> Exams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.Score> Scores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.CreateQuestion> CreateQuestions {get;set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineExams.Models.ExamRecord> ExamRecords { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate any help from anyone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You somehow managed to post the most useless portion of your entire code. Besides `using` statements I guess, but that's not much more useless. Well, here's your answer: "ok".

Comment: Are you using migrations?

Comment: Yes i have used migration but complaining of the new table not having primary key. I think the solution now is to drop and re-create some tables that i think responsible to the problem in the aspect of hierarchy because am actually mapping relationships  .

Comment: Could you please just give me an idea on how a typical online exam database table should be mapped in-terms of relationship and inheritance ?  a big thanks in advance.

Comment: when you get the primary key error, you should define primary keys for your tables, either with data annotation ([Key]) or fluent api (HasKey()). Your relationships depend on your actual POCO classes, you should look at a tutorial for that, though Code First Conventions should solve a lot of things there. There is no real need to think about inheritance when you already have your DbSets defined. Basic information also at the Code First Tutorial for EF.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.